# Spring data MongoDB adding arrays to an existing document

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Say I have the following Collections

```
    public @Data  class Customer {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @DBRef
    private List<Address> addressList= new ArrayList<Address>();
}
```

and

```
public @Data class  Address {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String address;
    private String type;
    private String customerID;
}
```

And each  Customer has multiple addresses, and I have implemented `MongoRepository`. Saving customer for the First time is working pretty well `customerRepo.save(customerObject)` and before calling the save I am persisting multiple Address Objects and then setting those to the `addressList`.
Next time when I am updating the same document and want to add a New set of Address to the existing list it is overwriting the whole `addressList` array. So basically what I have to do now to set new address like this`existingCustomerObject.getAddressList().addAll(my new List of address)` if there are thousand(or more than thousand) of elements or I am slicing the addressList array the following procedure won't be a good idea. My question is what is the best way to achieve this scenario? say if I don't want to use `MongoTemplate`. Is it possible Just using the `MongoRepository`

Comment: I don't think it is possible with just MongoRepositoy. You have to use mongotemplate and do a $pull

Comment: since I have added @DBRef to the child entries even usage of MongoRepositoy is not solving my problem because I want to prevent loading all of the child entries at a same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in that way. Previously i had the same situation, and I tried the following

1.`org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` even I have managed to manipulate the D`BObject` but functions like `$push` or `$set`(wrapping them under key) does not work over there.

2.`AbstractMongoEventListener` by overriding `onBeforeSave` but Object manipulation was not taking place during save.

However you can try altering the mentioned

you can try override `MongoRepository` save method, It would better if someone point to the right direction.
Otherwise for my scenario I had to create Custom repository(To update and delete document) which is working parallel with `MongoRepository` (for Insert and retrieve data/document), but I believe thats an ugly workaround. There has to be a cleaner way to do it.