# Change or override default Behavior of Mongorepository.save(document)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Is there any way to intercept or change the `document` before `MongoRepository.save(e)` updates it?

I am trying to push a subproperty inside and array in a document. I have tried to manipulate `DBObjects` by implementing  `converter`(using custom converter) but the `$push` operation did not work over there.

I think  to make it work I have to implement something like  `mongoOperation.update(dbObjectMatch,dbObjectUdate).`

I found `MongoRepositorysave(document)` doesn't support partial update, i.e write only the change to an existing document. I want to know the internal code of `MongoRepository.save` to override the default behavior.

I have implemented `MyRepositoryCustom` where I can override `save` by extending the same in `MyRepository`, which extends `MongoRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>` and then used `mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query,update,Clazz.class)` to achieve what I am looking for but I am not satisfied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have multiple, slightly different questions:

From your title:

> Change/Override Default Behaviour of Mongorepository Save() ( S save(S var1)) Method

You can use custom implementations to override the behavior of existing methods in Spring Data repositories. See [the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) how to do that. Your last paragraph suggests you already do that. Unfortunately you don't tell us why you aren't satisfied with this.

> Is there any way to intercept/change before Mongorepository Save() ( S save(S var1)) method For document update.

Yes a Spring Data MongoDB repository fires various life cycle  events for this purpose. Once again, [see the reference documentation for details](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).

> I want to know the Internal code of Mongorepository Save

What you are looking for is [`SimpleMongoRepository.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/support/SimpleMongoRepository.java) which delegates for almost all work to [`MongoTemplate.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java)

Comment: Hi, Jens Schauder  My main problem is I want to make a partial update for existing entry. but the `MongoRepository` update method is rewriting the whole Object. and I have the exact scenario of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510093/spring-data-mongodb-adding-arrays-to-an-existing-document. Expecting a solution fro you

Comment: i mean to say `save` method*

Comment: that is a completely different question. AND a duplicate as you write yourself.

Comment: No, you got me wrong, What I meant to say I have the same structure One-to-Many Relationship for my project. and this is not a duplicate Question. But you Ignored My main point which I have also mentioned In my Question **I want to make a partial update for existing entry** with the `save` method and without overriding.

Comment: The reason I am asking this for JPA (For SQL) it was that easy.

Comment: I am accepting this answer not because it solved my problem but this has the answers to my questions. A partial update is not possible without overriding `MongoRepository` or custom method for now.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [Lifecycle Events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).

Overriding repository base methods allows you to interact with the domain object itself but the mapping happens inside of `MappingMongoConverter`.

Saving an object will fire events such as

- [`BeforeSaveEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/event/BeforeSaveEvent.html)
- [`BeforeConvertEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/event/BeforeConvertEvent.html)
- [`AfterConvertEvent`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/event/AfterConvertEvent.html)

These events carry a reference to your saved object. `AfterConvertEvent` additionally exposes the mapped representation (`DBObject`) of your object which you can change/enhance.

You can listen to these events by configuring a listener bean such as `ApplicationListener<AfterConvertEvent>`.

Comment: tried `AbstractMongoEventListener<E>` did not solve my problem because `onBeforeSave` or `onBeforeConvert` gives you access to the `DBObject` only what I want to do Partial Update So I don't think `AbstractMongoEventListener` will work here. tried calling save from `onBeforeSave` method and end up with `StackOverflowError` (which is obvious)

Answer (score 0):

You can fragmentally override the MongoRepository by ensuring you match the signature of method in the custom interface.

E.g. If you want to override `save()` method, create a new interface like

```
interface CustomizedSave<T> {
  <S extends T> S save(S entity);
}
```

Implement this interface:

```
@Component
class CustomizedSaveImpl<T> implements CustomizedSave<T> {
  //This is optional, I added it to just show you can use it here
  MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public CustomizedSaveImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
  }

  public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    // Your custom implementation
  }
}
```

Extend the interface in the base MongoRepository like

```
interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>, CustomizedSave<User> {
}
```

This will ensure only save menthod gets overridden and rest stay as is.

Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior